# Wiring a 6 pin On/Off/On toggle switch (DC) 2 Pole

Tags: switches, dc, wiring

I bought a 2 pole 6 pin On/Off/On toggle switch that's for DC power, (25A 12V)
see here:
[Toggle Switch](https://www.12voltplanet.co.uk/on-off-on-toggle-switch-25-amps-at-12-volts-2-pole.html)

The only issue is that I have no idea how to wire it, as mentioned, it has labels on the back, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 with no indication of what's positive and negative.

What I would like to do with it, is connect two power sources, and a main device, is that even possible with this switch?

Basically, I have a Monitor that takes 12V DC, and I want to use, USB-C (Which is converted to 12V through a buck converter) and a DC power adapter, but the switch is used to switch between them, so flicking to the first On will use USB-C, and then the second On will use the adapter, again, is it even possible to do that with this switch? If it is, could anyone help me with wiring? Because there isn't any schematics or diagrams that explain how this switch is wired.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. The common on one pole of the switch is connected to the upper or lower tag depending on switch position. The other pole of the switch is the same and is electrically isolated from the first.*

- Connect the monitor + and - to the common tags.
- Connect one power source to the top tags, observing polarity.
- Connect the other power source to the bottom tags, observing polarity.

[image]

*Figure 2. Cross-section of a switch that was a serious problem on Apollo 15 due to a piece of wire floating around inside the switch. Source: [Apollo 15
Day 2: Checking the SPS](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap15fj/05day2_checking_sps.html).*

Don't buy stuff that doesn't have datasheets.

Comment: How would I know which one is positive and negative though? And thanks, I will make sure I pay attention to stuff not having a datasheet.

Comment: @jsotola: I've seen both (some have an internal toggle that reverses the lever toggle) but after an image search yours is much more common. Fixed.

Comment: @DanielMorris: You are free to decide yourself. Put all three positives on one side (the side I've labeled, for example) and all three negatives on the other.

Comment: @Transistor - Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: @Transistor - Also, I was talking about this to someone else, and they mentioned connecting a common ground? Do you think I need to do that? I'm assuming that means connecting all the negatives together?

Comment: If you're going to do that you wouldn't need a two pole switch, one would do. I wouldn't recommend it because you don't know that the negatives are fully isolated. Switching both poles avoids any problems and is just the same as unplugging one supply and plugging in the other.

Answer (score 1):

As a general note, always be wary of parts without datasheets!

It looks very similar to [this switch](http://spec_sheets.e-switch.com/specs/34-ST246D00.pdf) ([Digikey link](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/e-switch/ST246D00/EG4821-ND/2116300)) . You can see how this type of switch is generally wired in the bottom right "Schematics" section. In short, each of the 2 rows of pins are identical, just different sets of the same connections. The middle pin is your common (always part of either connection), whereas the pins on either side can be toggled to.

Are you only switching power and not video with your switch? If so, I don't see a problem with your idea. Your monitor 12V input sits on the middle pin, so while the switch is in the middle position, no power is delivered. USB-C power comes into the left pin, and the DC supply on the right pin. Being double pole, you could actually switch both the positive and negative connections.

Comment: Thank you for this. And I will pay attention to stuff without a datasheet next time. :) Also yes, I am only switching power, and so does it not matter then which is positive and negative?